# LibreOffice Indent table of content

Tags: libreoffice

I'm writing an essay and use 2,5 cm text indent. The original is 2 cm. But whenever I create a table of content that content goes back to 2 cm, and I haven't found a way to indent it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LibreOffice applies the paragraph style "`Contents [n]`" to ToC entries by default; `[n]` is the heading level. So, to indent the ToC entries, you will have to modify the the "`contents`" paragraph styles:

1. Menu "`Format`" -> "`Styles and Formatting`"
2. single-click on style entry (e.g. "`Contents 1`" for all top-level ToC entries) to select it
3. right-click and select "`Modify`" -> "`Indents and Spacing`" tab

Comment: Just a random question about Insert>Sections. The border of the section indent to 2 cm, the text in the section is correct though. I don't know if you can indent the borders to 2,5 cm, but then the text will have to indent more than 2,5 cm. So there is probably no purpose to make any edits for the borders.

Comment: @nicoX: I'm sorry but i fear i didn't understood. If you have another issue, it would be better to ask a new question so other users get notice of it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way preferably if you wish the indent to be applied for all pages and styles is:

1. Menu "`Format`"->"`Page`"
2. You can set the "`Margins`" to be what you prefer