# Indentation on Table of Contents

Tags: libreoffice

i'm having a problem with a Table of Contents on LibreOffice Writer. All my entries, from "Contents 1" to "Contents 5" are indented at the beginning of each line.

I've read several topics that says that the style Content [n] comes prepared by default to automatically indent on a ToC.

According to this question: [LibreOffice Indent table of content](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469671/libreoffice-indent-table-of-content/469707#469707), we should edit each style manually for getting each entry properly indented on a ToC.

What should i do? I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not. Editing each style of a ToC will fix the issue, but i strongly believe that this should be automatically, right?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? If you want to modify all the contents styles in one step, you may try to modify the Index style, since the contents styles inherit from index style. But this may affect other styles, too, that ingerit similarily from index.

Comment: Yes, it is indented by default.  And yes, the best way to remove the indent is to edit each Contents style.

Comment: @jim-k, i don't want to remove indent... i want to add it !!

Comment: @tohuwawohu I want to add indent to my Table of Contents entries

Comment: It would be clearer to show an example and the desired outcome.  Are you asking how to increase the indents?  If so, then the best way is to edit each Contents style.

Comment: Ok, i believe that i broke something in the defalut configuration for "Contents [n]" styles and for this reason, i edited all of those styles manually